# MySQL SELECT a row if the value between two tables increased

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table in mysql with IDs from osteoartritic patients and their KL grade throught different visits. I'd like to know a query to select and identify who is a rapid progressor (IDs whose kl grade increased from grade 0-1 to grade >=3 when compare two different visits (V00 vs V06; V03 vs V08; V06 vs V10)) and no rapid progressor (ID whose kl grade increse from 0-1 to 2 when compare the same visits). Column SIDE especify if the values are for the right or the left knee.

Here's some rows as example of my table (name of the table: KL_grade):

| ID | SIDE | V00XRKL | V03XRKL | V05XRKL | V06XRKL | V08XRKL | V10XRKL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

I tried this instruction to select rapid progressors, but it doesn't return all of them.

```
SELECT a.id, a.SIDE
from kl_grade a
left join (SELECT b.id, b.SIDE
            from kl_grade b
            where V03XRKL BETWEEN 0 and 1 and V08XRKL >= 3) b
on a.ID = b.id and a.SIDE = b.SIDE 
left join (SELECT c.id, c.SIDE
            from kl_grade c
            where V06XRKL BETWEEN 0 and 1 and V10XRKL >= 3) c
on a.ID = c.id and a.SIDE = c.SIDE 
where V00XRKL BETWEEN 0 and 1 and V06XRKL >= 3

UNION 

SELECT a.id, a.SIDE
from kl_grade a
right join (SELECT b.id, b.SIDE
            from kl_grade b
            where V03XRKL BETWEEN 0 and 1 and V08XRKL >= 3) b
on a.ID = b.id and a.SIDE = b.SIDE 
right join (SELECT c.id, c.SIDE
            from kl_grade c
            where V06XRKL BETWEEN 0 and 1 and V10XRKL >= 3) c
on a.ID = c.id and a.SIDE = c.SIDE 
where V00XRKL BETWEEN 0 and 1 and V06XRKL >= 3;
```

edit:
In order to look for rapid progressors between visits 0 and 6 I tried:

```
select ID 
CASE
    when V00XRKL < 2 and V06XRKL > 2
    then 'rapid progressor'
END
from kl_grade kg
```

but in return I get a syntax error:

SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when V00XRKL < 2 and V06XRKL > 2
then 'rapid progressor'
from kl_grade kg' at line 3

I look into mysql manual but and the syntax should be correct... I can't find what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Consider revising your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet!

Comment: *I get a syntax error* A comma between output expressions is lost.

Answer (score 0):

A normalised schema might look somewhat as follows:

```
table_a
ID  SIDE    
1   1   
1   2   
2   1   
2   2   
3   1   
3   2   

table_b
id table_a_ID v_type  value 
 1          2 V00XRKL     1     
 2          2 V00XRKL     1     
 3          3 V00XRKL     1     

 4          2 V03XRKL     1     
 5          2 V03XRKL     1     
 6          3 V03XRKL     1     

 7          2 V05XRKL     2     
 8          2 V05XRKL     2     
 9          3 V05XRKL     2     
10          3 V05XRKL     2     

11          1 V06XRKL     3     
12          1 V06XRKL     2     
13          2 V06XRKL     2     
14          2 V06XRKL     2     
15          3 V06XRKL     2     
16          3 V06XRKL     2     

17          1 V08XRKL     3
18          1 V08XRKL     3
19          2 V08XRKL     3
20          2 V08XRKL     3
21          3 V08XRKL     2
22          3 V08XRKL     3

23          1 V08XRKL     4
24          1 V08XRKL     4
25          2 V08XRKL     4
26          2 V08XRKL     4
27          3 V08XRKL     2
28          3 V08XRKL     4
```